# Why does await works with "setState" in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have been reading docs for almost a week now and searching to find an exact answer !
When I use inline `setState()` for a `onClick` event, It works perfectly fine but when I move the `setState()` to a function named `updateCount()` in my class, It does not work for the first time and I get the reason.

The problem is I added `async/await` to the function, strangely it works. ( I am aware of other methods )

**The question is why it works with async/await?**

(By the way when I use VS Code, I get this massage : `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.` but it actually has an effect so maybe that is a bug in react JS ?! )

Original code that **works fine** :

```
class LastTest extends Component {
    
    state = { count: 0 }
    componentDidMount() {
        document.title = `You clicked ${this.state.count} times`;
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        document.title = `You clicked ${this.state.count} times`;
    }
    render() {
        return ( 
            <div>
                <p>You clicked {this.state.count} times</p>
                <button onClick={() => this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })}>
                Click me
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Bad code** that does not update `count` for first click:

```
class LastTest extends Component {
    
    state = { count: 0 }
    componentDidMount() {
        document.title = `You clicked ${this.state.count} times`;
    }
    updateCount(){
        this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
        document.title = `You clicked ${this.state.count} times`;
    }
    render() {
        return ( 
            <div>
                <p>You clicked {this.state.count} times</p>
                <button onClick={() => this.updateCount()}>
                Click me
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Updated** code and added `async/await` to the function `updateCount()` :

```
class LastTest extends Component {
    
    state = { count: 0 }
    componentDidMount() {
        document.title = `You clicked ${this.state.count} times`;
    }
    async updateCount(){
        await this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
        document.title = `You clicked ${this.state.count} times`;
    }
    render() {
        return ( 
            <div>
                <p>You clicked {this.state.count} times</p>
                <button onClick={() => this.updateCount()}>
                Click me
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect the observation that "it works with `await`" may be a false positive and something else is happening.  `setState` is not a `Promise` to be awaited.  It's "asynchronous" in the sense that the operation will complete at some later time.  But it's not awaitable.

Comment: The question is why it works with async/await and I do not think this question is a duplicate. Please unclose this so experts can demonstrate.

Comment: You can remove the async/await and use a callback in your setstate, like this


``` updateCount(){
        this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 }, () => {
document.title = `You clicked ${this.state.count} times`
});
        
    }```

Comment: Isn't updating a react component's state considered to be an async task ?

Comment: Exactly but why it can't be awaited ? `setState` is not a promise as David mentioned right?

Comment: Most likely that, state updates are batched, awaiting flushes those changes and state changes are available after the await in the same function